# How to not initialize part of a struct

Tags: go

I want to combine what I think is called a *grouped global* with an *embedded lock* like this:

```
var stats struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    m map[string]statsEntry
}
```

Unfortunately for the map to be useful, it has to be made, so the code becomes:

```
var stats = struct {
  sync.RWMutex
  m map[string]statsEntry
}
{
  ???,
  make(map[string]statsEntry),
}
```

What to put instead of `???`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a type literal:

```
stats := struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    m map[string]statsEntry
}{
    sync.RWMutex{},
    make(map[string]statsEntry),
}
```

But since the zero value of `sync.RWMutex` is valid, you can skip it and specify the fields you're assigning

```
stats := struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    m map[string]statsEntry
}{
    m: make(map[string]statsEntry),
}
```

But it's often just clearer to define the type locally

```
type s struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    m map[string]statsEntry
}

stats = s{m: make(map[string]statsEntry)}
```

Comment: I always struggle finding type names for global variables because [I read](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/zD8tRKAmoJE) you shouldn't name them `var something somethingType`.